# WooCommerce multiple custom fields code

Tags: php, custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, html

I used a guide to add multiple custom fields to the general tab in the product post setting.

When I enter data into the fields, it saves and shows on the product page without the problem;
The problem is that when I erase them, data cleaned from fields but created divs and other HTML elements remain on the product page.

This is the code I used in functions.php in my theme folder:

```
// Custom field Type

?> <p class="form-field custom_field_type">
    <label for="custom_field_type"><?php echo __( 'ویژگی های کلیدی محصول', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
    <span class="wrap">
        <?php $custom_field_type = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true ); ?>  
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_one" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[0]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_two" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[1]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_three" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[2]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_four" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[3]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_five" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[4]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
        <input placeholder="<?php _e( '', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" type="text" name="_field_six" value="<?php echo $custom_field_type[5]; ?>" step="any" min="0" />
    </span>
    <span class="description"><?php _e( 'شش ویژگی کلیدی محصول را بنویسید', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span> </p> <?php
```

**and for saving also in functions.php**:

```
// Custom Field $custom_field_type = array(
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_one'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_two'] ),
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_three'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_four'] ),
    esc_attr( $_POST['_field_five'] ), esc_attr( $_POST['_field_six'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_field_type', $custom_field_type );
```

**in the single-product.php for showing:**

```
  <?php
       if (!empty( $custom_field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true))) {
    echo '<div id="vijegiha">';
      echo '<h3 id="vijegih3">ویژگی های کلیدی</h3>';
        echo '<ul>';
            foreach($custom_field_type as $vijegi)
            if (!empty( $vijegi )) {
                 echo '<li>'.$vijegi.'</li>';}
        echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';}else{} ?>
```

Comment: This might be one of those instances where an empty string is being stored, in which case `empty()` will return true. See what happens if you use `isset` in `if (!empty( $vijegi )) {` instead of `!empty` or perhaps `$vijegi !== ""`

Answer (score 0):

Not in stackoverflow nor stackexchange can`t answer my question. I dont know maybe they just can edit my writing dictation!. Anyway after searching in php courses my code is this now and works correctly:

```
<?php
$custom_field_type = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_type', true);
$custom_field_type = array_filter($custom_field_type, 'strlen');
if (count($custom_field_type)) {
        echo '<div id="vijegiha">';
          echo '<h3 id="vijegih3">ویژگی های کلیدی</h3>';
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($custom_field_type as $vijegi)
                if (!empty( $vijegi )) {
                     echo '<li>'.$vijegi.'</li>';}
            echo '</ul>';
        echo '</div>';
}else{} ?>
```